# Angular controller doesn't update after binding array

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular controller which I use to show some data. Now I can bind the array from my php file, but the controllers doesn't seem to update. The console.log shows the array has been bound, but there's no result in my html.

html:

```
<div class="motivatie-edit front-end-edit" ng-app="MotivatieApp">
    <div ng-controller="ResultaatController as results">
        <div id="motivatie_resultaat" class="resultaat" ng-repeat="r in results.motivaties">
            {{r.motivatie}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app:

```
var app = angular.module('MotivatieApp', []);

    (function () {
    app.controller('ResultaatController', function ($http) {
        $http.post('ajax_crud.php', {motivatie: 'get'}).
                success(function (json, status, headers, config) {
                    app.motivaties = json;
                    console.log(app);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });
    });
})();
```

php:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

/* get motivatie */
if ($request->motivatie == 'get') {
    $motivatieArray = array();
    $customer1 = array(
        'motivatie' => 'John Doe',
    );
    $motivatieArray[] = $customer1;
    $customer2 = array(
        'motivatie' => 'Jane Doe',
    );
    $motivatieArray[] = $customer2;

    echo json_encode($motivatieArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you completely misunderstood how angular data binding works. data binding in angular is implemented through $scope, refer to this [official guide about scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

angular use [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to interpolate scope variable into html template.

So in your case, you need to do 2 things

1. fetch data from php file and assign to $scope variable

var app = angular.module('MotivatieApp', []);

```
app.controller('ResultaatController',['$scope','$http' function ($scope,$http) {
  $http.post('ajax_crud.php', {motivatie: 'get'}).
            success(function (json, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.motivaties = json; // assign ajax result to $scope here
            })
});
}]);
```

2. use motivaties in html

```html
<div class="motivatie-edit front-end-edit" ng-app="MotivatieApp">
    <div ng-controller="ResultaatController">
        <div id="motivatie_resultaat" class="resultaat" ng-repeat="r in motivaties">
            {{r}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery ajax, so that's out side the angular knowledge, if you do something out side of angular then you have to tell there are changes to update,

to do that use  `$scope.$apply()`

```
jQuery.post("ajax_crud.php", data, function (json) {
        app.motivaties = json;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, "json");
```

**OR** the **best thing to do** is use angular [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

Since your using angular there is no need to use jquery ajax in the controllers.

Comment: Changed the post to $http service. Again the array is bound, but no results in html. So it all seems to work except for the update of {{r.motivatie}}...

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,

```
app.controller('ResultaatController', function ($http) {
    var vm = this;
    $http.post('ajax_crud.php', {motivatie: 'get'}).
            success(function (json, status, headers, config) {
               vm.motivaties = json;
                console.log(vm);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
});
```

DEMO plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/5MVA24ydgeH2zhHYpTLT?p=preview